# Escaping triple nested quotes in EL

Tags: jsp, el, quote

I have a piece of code that requires quotes inside quotes inside quotes.

```
<c:if test="${details.runDes == '<bean:write name='loadBean' property='execTypeDes' />'}">
```

What is the proper way to quote the third layer?

I tried

```
<c:if test="${details.runDes == '<bean:write name=&quot;loadBean&quot; property=&quot;execTypeDes&quot; />'}"
```

and

```
<c:if test="${details.runDes == '<bean:write name=`loadBean` property=`execTypeDes` />'}">
```

but neither work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used and it worked
`<c:if test="${details.runDes == &quot;<bean:write name='loadBean' property='execTypeDes' />&quot;}">`